# Check for a specific set of characters(of a password) in a string

Tags: java, string, if-statement

I have to write a program which checks a password.

- If the password entered by the user is 'bolt', it will display '`The password is valid`'
- Otherwise it will display '`The password is invalid`'.

The program is working only for the *if* part but not for the *else*.
That is when I input *bolt*, it displays the correct message.
But when I enter something other than *bolt*, it does not display '`The password is invalid`'.
I have been told to test for all four characters that is to use *char.At*.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your 4-character password:");
        String password = input.next();

        for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {
            if (password.charAt(i) == 'B' || password.charAt(i) == 'b')
                if (password.charAt(i + 1) == 'O'
                        || password.charAt(i + 1) == 'o')
                    if (password.charAt(i + 2) == 'L'
                            || password.charAt(i + 2) == 'l')
                        if (password.charAt(i + 3) == 'T'
                                || password.charAt(i + 3) == 't') {

                            System.out.println("The password is valid");
                        }
                        else {
                            System.out.println("The password is invalid!");

                        }
        }
}
```

Comment: I think your else is simply at the wrong depths.

Comment: Any solution that uses some form of loop is sub-par. If you know the password consists of 4 chars you should first check for null, then for string length and only then start comparing characters. At that point you know the input string is 4 chars and hence there's no need for a loop (that's what my proposed solution below does).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your updated question:

```
String password = input.next().toLowerCase();
String correctPassword = "bolt";

if (password.length() != correctPassword.length()) {
    System.out.println("Not valid");
    return;
}

for (int i = 0; i < correctPassword.length(); i++) {
    if (password.charAt(i) != correctPassword.charAt(i)) {
        System.out.println("Not valid");
        return;
    }
}
System.out.println("Valid");
```

In your code there are two problems,
1. Your for loop doesn't serve any purpose because you have checked the whole password in the first iteration itself. Your second iteration would cause `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

2. You didnt see the invalid password message because, your else condition is applied only to the innermost `if` (which checks for the char "T" or "t").

   So, if the provided password starts with "BOL" but last char is different like "BOLA" or "BOLB", then you would see the invalid message. But if the first three char fail, then it wont execute the else.

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks a lot! But can you please tell me where I went wrong in my codes? I mean why the _else_ statement was not working

Comment: I have updated the answer. Let me know if more explanation is needed.

Comment: Thanks, I understood it. Using the same method, how could I have improved the _for_ loop and the _else_ statement for it to have worked?

Answer (score 2):

It would be more readable to check using `equalsIgnoreCase()`:

```
String password= input.next();
if(password.equalsIgnoreCase("bolt"){
   System.out.println("The password is valid");
}
else{
   System.out.println("The password is invalid!");
}
```

Comment: An unrelated suggestion, use `"bolt".equalsIgnoreCase(password)` instead to avoid `NullPointerException` in `password`.

Comment: sure..or you can always validate for nulls.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just check for String equality directly?

```
String password= input.next();
if("bolt".equals(password))) {
  System.out.println("Valid password");
} else {
  System.out.println("InValid password");
}
```

Or use `equalsIgnoreCase()` if you'd also consider `BOLT` or `Bolt` valid.

If you need to implement this without `equals` you could use something like this:

```
if (password != null && 
    password.length() == 4 && 
    (password.charAt(0) == 'B' || password.charAt(0) == 'b') && 
    ...) {
  System.out.println("Valid password");
} else {
  System.out.println("InValid password");
}
```

Comment: I have been told to use char.At

Answer (score 1):

I'did use `string.matches` function which accepts regex as  argument. `(?i)` helps to do a case-insensitive match.

```
if(string.matches("(?i)bolt")) 
{
System.out.println("Valid password");
}
else {System.out.println("InValid password");}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is not making much sense. You should probably use a character array an then check sequentially. Another small thing is that the `else` block is associated with the last `if` statement. Where it should be attached to the first `if`. This is one place where you need to use braces intelligently.